# Method where to add up all numbers in an array

Tags: java, arrays, methods

I need to create a method where all clothes, tuiton, transportation, food, housing and books arrays add up to that point.
For example a print out has to look something like this

> Expenses as of Nov 4, 2011:
>
> Tuition: $3200
>
> Food: $2600
>
> Clothes: $600
>
> Books: $450
>
> Total expenses: $6850

^those numbers are given as an example not the ones i have below.

this is my code

```
public class Budget{

  ///////////////fields////////////////




  int clothes[]= {100, 110, 120, 130, 140, 150, 160, 170, 180, 190, 200, 210};
  int tuition[] = {200, 200, 200, 200, 200, 200, 200, 200, 200, 200, 200, 200};
  int transportation[]={100, 110, 120, 130, 140, 150, 160, 170, 180, 190, 200, 210};
  int food[]={80, 80, 80, 80, 80, 80, 80, 80, 80, 80, 80, 80};
  int housing[]={150, 150, 150, 150, 150, 150, 150, 150, 150, 150, 150};
  int books[]= {200, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 300, 0, 0, 0, 0};
    int i=0; // this is arbitrary. Never hard code numbers unless that number is never going to change. in that case you make a variable and define it.

  private int expenseName[][] = {clothes, tuition, transportation, food, housing, books};

/////////constructors///////////////
    public Budget() {}

  public Budget(int name) {this.expenseName[i][i] = name;}

    public Budget(int name[], int clothes, int tuition, int transportation, int food, int housing, int books)
    {
      this.expenseName[i] = name;
      this.clothes[i] = clothes;
      this.tuition[i] = tuition;
      this.transportation[i] = transportation;
      this.food[i] = food;
      this.housing[i] = housing;
      this.books[i] = books;
    }


 /////////////methods///////////
public int getexpenseName() {return expenseName[i][i];}

public int getclothes() {return clothes[i];}//change the I
public int gettuition() {return tuition[i];}
public int gettransporation() {return transportation[i];}
public int getfood() {return food[i];}
public int gethousing() {return housing[i];}
public int books() {return books[i];}

public void setExpenseName(int name)
{
  this.expenseName[i][i] = name;
}
```

Comment: This is really crappy code. Firstly, indent properly, secondly, you have to declare your variables at the top of the class. Please do that stuff so we can respond better.

Comment: @DhaivatPandya Perhaps a different approach would be more suitable? We're not all superstar Java devs. And you don't *have* to declare your properties at the top, it's just conventional and convenient to do so. While I agree the original code was... sub-optimal, seems like a more mentor-y approach might fare better.

Answer (score 1):

This is the code to sum all integers in a 2D array.

```
int sum = 0;
for (int[] a : expenseName) {
    for (int n : a) {
        sum += n;
    }
}
```